# When user swipes on a UIButton the UIScrollView stops working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have found that when I try to scroll the scrollivew, if you are dragging one of the buttons, it prevents the scrollview from scrolling. If you are dragging an empty part of the scrollview that doesn't contain anything, it will scroll. Does anyone know a solution to this?

My .h file just has a scrollview and a image on top:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bodyImage;
```

my .m file has this to enable scrolling

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 1136)];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I then added a button on the top of the image and push it to another view controller.

I can see why it's just clicking the button and going to the next view, as the button is on top! I basically just want the user to be able to scroll around the page, and when he/she actually clicks, then it goes to the next view!

Thanks for you help everyone, I do really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting `UIScrollView's` `delaysContentTouches` property to `NO`.

Comment: Do I just apply this in the -(void) viewDidLoad? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are dragging the button, UIButton is the view which is FirstResponder to the touch event. This is the reason why scrollView is not scrolling while dragging on button.

Set UIScrollView's `delaysContentTouches` property to NO, as suggest by @Hitendra. This will mostly solve the issue.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some of you're sample code here ... so we can look into it